# Im trying to count variables in a list for assignment, then assign it to number (0,6)

Tags: python, loops

My assignment is to make a dice poker game, and the current question im up to is assigning the player hand a rank i.e. an integer value between 0 and 6.

here is the full question

"Determine the rank of the player’s hand (i.e. an integer value between 0 and 6 as described in the section 'Dice Poker
Game Play and Rules'). Hint: Use the die_count list that holds how many times each die face value was rolled in
order to determine the rank of the hand."

how do i go about assigning the hand a rank based on die count?
 i am not suppose to use .count() or any other kind of list methods

Here is my code so far

```
import dice  
import random

player_hand = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
computer_hand = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
die_count = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
die_count2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

i = 0    
l = 0 

for x in range(5):
    player_hand[x] = random.randint(1,6)    
    computer_hand[x] = random.randint(1,6)

while i < 5 :
    die_value = player_hand[i]    
    die_count[die_value] = die_count[die_value] + 1
    i = i + 1

while l < 5 :
    die_value = computer_hand[l]    
    die_count2[die_value] = die_count2[die_value] + 1
    l = l + 1

print ("Player's hand:")
dice.display_hand(player_hand, 5)

print (" ")    
print ("Computer's hand:\n")    
dice.display_hand(computer_hand, 5)

print (str(die_count))
print (str(die_count2))
```

Comment: "...as described in the section 'Dice Poker Game Play and Rules'..." First you have to understand the rules for the game. If you were doing this by hand, how would you calculate the rank? Describe the steps **in words** before attempting to write any code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list with the counts of dice values:

```
dice_count_player=[player_hand.count(x) for x in range(1,7)]
```

If you really don't want to use count, then you can do this part as you wrote it in the question, but little bit shorter:

```
dice_count_player = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for v in player_hand:
    dice_count_player[v] += 1
```

If you want the counts in reverse order:

```
dice_count_player_desc = sorted(dice_count_player, reverse=True)
```

You can then calculate the value from this like:

```
if dice_count_player_desc[0] == 5:
    print("Five of a kind")
elif dice_count_player_desc[0] == 4:
    print("Four of a kind")
...
elif dice_count_player_desc[0] == 2 and  dice_count_player_desc[1] == 2:
    print("Two pairs")
```

A full example:

```
import random

player_hand = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
computer_hand = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
dice_count_player = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
dice_count_computer = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for x in range(6):
    player_hand[x] = random.randint(1,6)    
    computer_hand[x] = random.randint(1,6)

print ("Player's hand:")
print(player_hand)

print ()    
print ("Computer's hand:\n")    
print(computer_hand)

for v in player_hand:
    dice_count_player[v] += 1

for v in computer_hand:
    dice_count_computer[v] += 1

dice_count_player_desc = sorted(dice_count_player, reverse=True)

if dice_count_player_desc[0] == 5:
    print("Five of a kind")
elif dice_count_player_desc[0] == 4:
    print("Four of a kind")
elif dice_count_player_desc[0] == 3 and  dice_count_player_desc[1] == 2:
    print("Full house")
elif max(dice_count_player) == 1 and  (dice_count_player[1] == 0 or dice_count_player[6] == 0):
    print("Straight")
elif dice_count_player_desc[0] == 3:
    print("Three of a kind")
elif dice_count_player_desc[0] == 2 and  dice_count_player_desc[1] == 2:
    print("Two pairs")
elif dice_count_player_desc[0] == 2 and  dice_count_player_desc[1] < 2:
    print("One pair")
else:
    print("Bust")
```

Comment: so for two pair the list needs 2 , 2 in it 
how do i get it to search for two of the same number in list

Comment: I've appended one example for two pairs. Hope it helps.

Comment: and i cant use .count() method for criteria

Comment: @MarcusPaulson OK. "suppose" has not meant "criteria" for me. I've added an alternative.

Comment: @MarcusPaulson OK, I've appended a (not full) working example.

Comment: how would you do it without the sort (reverse )
as it might be against my marking criteria just to be safe

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Tip for the future: You decrease the likelihood of a good answer when you exclude important information, such as the rules of the game you're programming. There appear to be multiple similar, yet different sets of rules for dice poker. It would be useful to know which you are using. Make sure to include things like this.

For instance, it's unclear why there are 7 elements in `die_count`, as a die has 6 sides. I can only assume that you're using the rules where 1 can be either a 1 *or* an ace. But if that's the case, then any count of 6s should be at index 5, and not 6 - i.e. if you role five 6s, then `die_count` should be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0]`, but you're program computes `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]`. Also, you only use the values 1-6 as indices for `die_count`, which means the first element (index 0) isn't used at all.

I used the dice poker rules found [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_Dice), which obviously deviate from your rules (e.g. 9 hands/ranks instead of 7). My code should still be helpful, and you can adapt it as needed. My code also assumes the face values of the dice don't affect the rank, i.e. a pair of 2s has the same rank as a pair of 6s. As a consequence I've shortened the `die_count_*` variables to 6 elements, because a pair of ones and a pair of "aces" is really the same thing, and aces cannot be used in either high or low straights.

The actual ranking process takes place in the function `rank_hand` using the dictionary `rank_dict`. I've excluded your `dice` module because I have no idea what it does or where to get it (it doesn't seem to play a roll in the hand ranking, anyway). I've added abundant comments so you understand what each part does - the code is actually quite compact without them.

```python
from random import randint

hand_play, die_count_play = [0] * 5, [0] * 6
hand_comp, die_count_comp = [0] * 5, [0] * 6

# The work done in your three loops can be done in one for-loop.
for i in range(5):
    hand_play[i], hand_comp[i] = randint(1,6), randint(1,6)
    die_count_play[hand_play[i]-1] += 1
    die_count_comp[hand_comp[i]-1] += 1


# Put the rankings in a dictionary with tuples corresponding to hands as keys.
rank_dict = {                 (5,):8, # five of a kind
                              (4,):7, # four of a kind
                            (2, 3):6, # full house
                (0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1):5, # high straight
                (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0):4, # low straight
                              (3,):3, # three of a kind
                            (2, 2):2, # two pairs
                              (2,):1  # one pair
              }

def rank_hand(die_count, rank_dict = rank_dict):
    """
    Take in list (length == 6) where each element is a count of the number of 
    times the digits 1-6 occur in throw of 5 dice. Return a hand ranking using 
    a dictionary of rankings `rank_dict`.
    """

    # If max value is two then key is either (2, 2) or (2,).
    if max(die_count) == 2:
        rank = rank_dict[tuple([c for c in die_count if c == 2])]

    # If max value is 1 then hand is either high or low straight, or no hand.
    elif max(die_count) == 1:

        # One of the values, first or last, must be 0 if hand is a high/low 
        # straight. If not, then there's no hand.
        if 0 in die_count[0::5]:
            rank = rank_dict[tuple(die_count)]
        else:
            rank = 0

    # If not a pair, straight, or no hand, then it must be one of remaining 
    # hands.
    else:
        rank = rank_dict[tuple(set([c for c in die_count if c > 1]))]

    return rank


# Call rank_hand on die counts for player and computer.
rank_play = rank_hand(die_count_play)
rank_comp = rank_hand(die_count_comp)

print(f"Player's rank:   {rank_play}\n" +
      f"Player's hand:   {hand_play}\n" + 
      f"Die count:       {die_count_play}\n" + 30*"-"
      )

print(f"Computer's rank: {rank_comp}\n" +
      f"Computer's hand: {hand_comp}\n" + 
      f"Die Count:       {die_count_comp}"
      )
```